# How can I have an image float left and a text box float right and both scale to the same height depending on screen size?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'll reference the following page since it's exactly what I'm aiming for:

http://acme-world.com/products/industrial-fencing/store-room-walls/

I want to have two divs side by side, both taking up 50% of their container. The left will be an image. The right will be a text box.

As the screen shrinks/expands, the image and the text box will scale to the same height while the image remains the same size and centered.

Thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zwxu6vbr/

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the 'li' element like a div in this case.

```
<style>
#main{
width:100%;
}

#main ul {
display: block;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#main li {
width:49.5%;
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
#main li img{
width:100%;
}

</style>



<div id='main'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src='image.png'>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src='image.png'>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```